# How to make a function that will iterate through the columns in a pandas dataframe and return unique values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
training_data = [
    ['Green',3,'Apple'],
    ['Yellow',3,'Apple'],
    ['Red',1,'Grape'],
    ['Red',1,'Grape'],
    ['Yellow',3,'Lemon']
]
def unique_values(df,col):
     return set([row[col] for row in df])

unique_values(training_data,1)

output = {1,3}
```

I want to be able to do this but with a pandas data frame instead of a list

Comment: You can `df.agg(pd.Series.unique)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) to find unique values in a column.

Create a dataframe from your list like this:

```
In [1974]: import pandas as pd

In [1975]: df = pd.DataFrame(training_data, columns = ['color', 'number', 'fruit'])

In [1986]: df
Out[1986]: 
    color  number  fruit
0   Green       3  Apple
1  Yellow       3  Apple
2     Red       1  Grape
3     Red       1  Grape
4  Yellow       3  Lemon
```

Then have your function like this:

```
In [1983]: def unique_values(df,col):
      ...:     return df[col].unique().tolist()
      ...:
```

Run your function like this:

```
In [1988]: unique_values(df, 'color')
Out[1988]: ['Green', 'Yellow', 'Red']

In [1989]: unique_values(df, 'fruit')
Out[1989]: ['Apple', 'Grape', 'Lemon']

In [1990]: unique_values(df, 'number')
Out[1990]: [3, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> training_data = [
...     ['Green',3,'Apple'],
...     ['Yellow',3,'Apple'],
...     ['Red',1,'Grape'],
...     ['Red',1,'Grape'],
...     ['Yellow',3,'Lemon']
... ]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(training_data, columns = ['color', 'number', 'fruit'])
>>> df.head()
    color  number  fruit
0   Green       3  Apple
1  Yellow       3  Apple
2     Red       1  Grape
3     Red       1  Grape
4  Yellow       3  Lemon
>>> df.number.unique()
array([3, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def unique_values(df,column):
        return set(df[column])
```

This also worked after turning the list into a data frame, thank you both!